# Retrieve details from AttributeError object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am enumerating some objects in a list, which may or may not have certain properties. If a property does not exists, I get the `AttributeError`. What I want to do is to catch the exception object and retrieve the specific property that causes the error and set it to an empty string. I don't see any method in the `AttributeError` object to retrieve the said attribute.

Partial code here:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()
for account in c.Win32_Account():
    try:
        print(f"Name: {account.Name}, FullName: {account.FullName}, LocalAccount: {account.LocalAccount}, Domain: {account.Domain}")
    except AttributeError as error:
        # How do I retreive the attribute in question from the exception object?
```

Answer (score 0):

Per original post, you want to "retrieve the specific property that causes the error and set it to an empty string".

if you just wanted to print the string use getattr:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI ()
for account in c.Win32_Account():
    print(f"Name: {getattr(account, 'Name', "")}, FullName: {getattr(account, 'FullName', "")}, LocalAccount: {getattr(account, 'LocalAccount', "")}, Domain: {getattr(account, 'Domain', "")}")
```

if you want to actually overwrite the missing values use hasattr and setattr:

```
for account in c.Win32_Account():
    for attr in ['Name', 'FullName', 'LocalAccount', 'Domain']:
        if not hasattr(account, attr):
            setattr(account, attr, "")
```

Comment: This assumes there is a valid default to use in place of missing attribute.

Comment: Also, you are just *ignoring* that there was an error. There are legitimate reasons to raise an error if an attribute is missing altogether.

Comment: per OP: retrieve the specific property that causes the error and set it to an empty string

Answer (score -1):

Every `Exception` object stores its arguments in the `.args` property. The argument to an `AttributeError` object is a string that contains the **object** on which the *property access is being used* and the **property** being *accessed*.

The format of this message looks like-

```
('|")object_name('|") object has no attribute ('|")property_name('|")
```

Where `('|")` means "either **matching** double quotes or single quotes"

You can extract both the object name and property name using this regex-

```regex
(?:\'|")(\w+)(?:\'|")
```

So the final implementation would look like-

```py
import wmi
import re

c = wmi.WMI ()
for account in c.Win32_Account():
    try:
        print(f"Name: {account.Name}, FullName: {account.FullName}, LocalAccount: {account.LocalAccount}, Domain: {account.Domain}")
    except AttributeError as error:
        property_name = re.findall(r'(?:\'|")(\w+)(?:\'|")', error.args[0])[-1]
```